# What started the smoke or fire behind Darth Maul?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, lightsaber

In Episode 1, when Darth Maul and Obi-Wan Kenobi are fighting, Obi-Wan cuts off one blade of Maul's double-bladed lightsaber, and it looks like smoke or fire starts in the corner behind Darth Maul. What's the explanation of this?

As a kid I thought that it was the cut-off lightsaber that landed behind Maul and damaged the wall/ground. But I am not sure since Obi-Wan destroyed the blade by cutting its hilt, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: A screenshot of the scene in question might help jog the memories of those of us who haven't seen these abomina-- er, I mean, *films* recently.

Answer (score 12):

It is the second half of his lightsaber hitting the ground.

When the double lightsaber is cut in half, one of the halves falls behind him to the his right (left, from our perspective). It is still turned on even though he is no longer holding it.

[image]

When it hits the ground it causes a bunch of sparks and then switches off.

[image]

You can see the smoking from the damage it caused (right side whiff of smoke).

[image]

The entire fight sequence can be seen here. The relevant parts are just after 4:00 minutes.

Comment: That score was the only good thing to come from those damn films.

Comment: Watching the video (haven't watched TPM in years) it occurs to me that if the Jedi went down so easy from multiple blaster fire in RotS, couldn't Amidala and her cadre just open fire and take out Darth Maul?

Comment: @MichaelItzoe maybe, if they're willing to lose a good portion (or all) of their cadre in the process.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I disagree. The only redeeming thing for me is the fight at the end of each one. Maul vs. Jedi, Yoda vs. Dooku, Yoda vs. Palpatine. The rest is awful... except maybe the score.